# Simple move_base example without sensors?

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a small, custom robot. I'm trying to learn the ROS navigation stack in this order:

1. Set up my robot to move by teleoperation and publish odometry. (DONE)
2. Use move_base to drive to a goal position (/move_base_simple/goal) assuming no obstacles and using no sensors.
3. Add sensors and obstacle avoidance with no a priori map.
4. Use gmapping to generate a map.

I'm stuck on #2 right now. I've tried to use a global configuration that has "rolling_window: true" and "static_map: false", as suggested, but move_base seems to go into recovery modes right away. (Local configuration is similar.) Can someone point me to an example of using move_base with neither a static map nor sensors? Or tell me how to figure out why a recovery mode is being triggered?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240009/simple-move_base-example-without-sensors?/) by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1563 on 2016-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please provide your costmap (i.e. move_base) configuration. Also, I highly suggest you use the layered costmap configuration which was introduced in ROS Hydro.

Take a look at the way the configs are handled in the Husky as an example, although it is a little complicated with the multiple param files:

https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/indigo-devel/husky_navigation/launch/move_base.launch

Off the top of my head, if move_base is going into recovery mode, I'm sure it's broadcasting some error messages that you could capture in this question. It's likely unable to generate a plan, which could be due to any number of things, such as the initial values in the costmap (track_unknown_space=False, since you have no sensors to clear space)? the size of the global/local costmaps, etc.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2016-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-08-08**:
Thanks, I was meaning to update the question. I have compared the Husky and Turtlebot setups, and I was able to get it running without sensors. I had some configuration errors, which are now fixed. I still have problems, but I think they are due to faulty local_planner params.

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2016-08-08**:
I'll get my minimal example working and link to it, once I work out the remaining problems.